# how to load a widget using jquery

Tags: jquery

i am using a widget from this site (newsfiber.com). the widget is not loading using $.ajax() which is what should be used.  i am posting here because i have not been able to get help from them.
 below is a sample

```
$("#link").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: widget.php,
      data: info,
      success: function(dd){
         $("#mydiv").html(dd);
      }
   });
});
```

the code in the widget.php document

%2F%2F&n=eng&y=">

```
<div name="_dsnnginf_634080201465X579_" id="_dsnnginf_634080201465X579_" style="font-weight: 400; text-align: left; padding: 0.2em; background-color: #E9E9F0; font-size: 95%; font-family: Georgia,Palatino,Arial,Times,Times New Roman,serif;">
   <a style="text-decoration: none; color: #0000EE;" href="http://www.newsfiber.com/p/s/h?v=C%2FSport%2FComplex+Coordination%2F&n=eng&y=" target="_blank">
      Sport / Complex Coordination
   </a> at 
   <a style="text-decoration: none; color: #0000EE;" href="http://www.newsfiber.com/" target="_blank">
      www.newsfiber.com
   </a>
</div>
```

here is a sample [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oqybdu9p/2/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons of your problem. If you want to have a better answer, please provide the link to the page, where you're using it, or put it in jsfiddle or elsewhere. And please look through console in browser to look for the mistakes and tell us if there are any.

1. You may not be calling your click event inside $(document).ready(function(){
   ...(here is where your event should be)...
   }); If you aleready knew that, sorry, But I should mantioned it.
2. I don't really understand, what your "data:info" line do.
3. Is there a php seted up on your server or, maybe, you're using a local project?

So please provide some more information here, for community to answer your question quickly and correctly.

Best regards!

Comment: the click event is inside $(document).ready(). the line "data:info" is the information that is sent to the widget.php file by the $.ajax() and i am currently working with xampp (localhost)